# "step through" in VS2012 only go to my function, not into the library's function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

> "step through" in VS2012 only go to my function, not into the library's function

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean "step through" or something else?

Comment: Well done @MatsPetersson.  I thought he meant "the `throw`statement" !

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "step into" and "step over"?  Or do you mean that when you "step into" a library function, it steps over it?

Comment: I mean when I debug my code(press F11) I don't want to into the library function but just into mine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting under Debug->Options->General saying "Enable Just My Code" by default. You might want to uncheck that.

And, of course, you need to have the source for the library to step into it.